# Setting ImageView for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to use this code for UIImageView in cellForRowAtIndexPath without results:

```
cell.favImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritedItem.png"];
```

The image is in the bundle, correct spelling and format and all, it just won't display. Image file is located in a group "images" but that should not matter.
How can I display this image??

Another ImageView finds an image name string in plist dictionary, this is working fine:

```
cell.flagImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[sortedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Flag"]];
```

Ps. using a custom prototype cell and Xcode 4/storyboard.

Comment: really weird. Suggest check the image names again, and use another image to test

Comment: try to place your cell.flagImageView.image = blablabla, outside (below) the if(cell == nil) block. It looks like you try to relaod table's data, and the needed cells are visible, so they are not nil, so, if your image setting is inside the block, it is not executed. Also, check if the tha bable outlet is hooked in interface builder.

Comment: This imageview is not displayed no matter if I set the image in storyboard utilites or anything, the whole imageview seems just dead.. Made the property and synthesized in Cell.h/.m, connected outlet to imageview and wrote this code, cannot see why it's not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my app look. I use Dynamic Prototyping Table and custom cells.

[image: ss]

My storyboard is like below.

[image: ss]

The point is that you should set **tag** of image view as below.

[image: ss]

Don't forget to set the **cell identifier** same with that in code. And the code is below:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.jpg"];
```

Comment: Thanks weed, not actually the answer but your post made me take a check through utilities, and it looks like my dog has changed the UIImageView class and stuff.. :P